# I want to use parallel-ssh to run a bash script on multiple servers, but it simple prints the echo statements

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, parallel-processing

I have a bash script called `sr_run_batch.sh` which does super resolution of images. Now I want to do testing on different servers in parallel at the same time. ie. 1 Virtual machine at one given point of time. then 2 virtual machines at one point of time , 3 and then 4.
I tried writing into it the commands

```
for host in $(cat hosts.txt); do ssh "$host" "$command" >"output.$host"; done 
ssh-keygen && for host in $(cat hosts.txt); do ssh-copy-id $host; done
```

where the file `hosts.txt` contains the list of servers: `username@ip`(format) but when I run this, it gives me substitution error

Hence, I tried pssh (parallel-ssh)

```
pssh -h hosts-file -l username -P $command
```

command being `./sr_run_batch.sh`

but it didn't run, so I modified this to

```
pssh -h hosts-file -l ben -P -I<./sr_run_batch.sh
```

But, for some unknown reason, it just prints the echo statements in the code.
here is the code :

```
NList=(5)    
VList=(1)    
FList=("input/flower1.jpg" "input/flower2.jpg" "input/flower3.jpg" "input/flower4.jpg")    
IList=("320X240"            "640X480"           "1280X960"          "1920X1200")    
SList=(2 3)    
for VM in ${VList[@]}; do

    for ((index=0; index < ${#FList};)) do
        file=$FList[$index]
        image_size=$IList[$index]
        width=`echo $image_size|cut -d "X" -f1`
        height=`echo $image_size|cut -d "X" -f2`
        for scale_factor in ${SList[@]}; do
            for users in ${NList[@]}; do 
                echo "V: $VM, " "F: $file, " "S: $scale_factor, " "I: $width $height , " "N: $users"
                for i in `seq 1 $users` ; do
                    ./sr_run_once.sh $file $width $height $scale_factor &
                done
                wait
            done # for users            
        done # for scale_factor
    done # for index
done # for VM
exit 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you also tried to use pssh with a simple bash-script so see if the communication is set up ok?

```
$ pssh -h hosts.txt -A -l ben -P -I<./uptime.sh
Warning: do not enter your password if anyone else has superuser
privileges or access to your account.
Password: 
10.0.0.67:  11:06:50 up 28 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
[1] 11:06:50 [SUCCESS] 10.0.0.67
10.0.0.218:  11:06:50 up 24 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.05, 0.20
[2] 11:06:50 [SUCCESS] 10.0.0.218
```